# How to add sprites around the perimeter of a circle in phaser-framework

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

There is a game world. And inside the game world, there is a small circle. How can I add a circle of sprites around the perimeter so that it does not go beyond the circle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is more general about how to calculate the coordinates of a circle.

Typically you can calculate circle positions using **sine** and **cosine**, and in JavaScript and Phaser you could do it something like this:

```
addSpritesInCircle: function(xpivot, ypivot, radius, amount) {

    // add sprites in a circle
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        // divide sprites evenly around the circle
        var angle = 360.0 * (i / amount);

        // calculate circle coordinates
        var xpos = xpivot + (Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * angle / 360.0) * radius);
        var ypos = ypivot + (Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * angle / 360.0) * radius);

        // add phaser sprite
        var sprite = this.game.add.sprite(xpos, ypos, 'mysprites', 'alienfoe1');

        // optionally also add to a group for handling/updates later
        this.myAliensGroup.add(sprite);
    };
}
```